# Python - add mysql entry in dynamic table

Tags: python, mysql

I would like to add some python-dictionary data in to dynamic mysql tables, but I'm stuck at line 12:

```
## INSERT DATA TO TABLE
for key,val in j_decoded["one-wire"].items():
    try:
        rom = key.encode('utf-8')
        temperatuur = val["temperatuur"]
        createsqltable = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `%s` (
                 id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                 created_on TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                 timestamp TIMESTAMP,
                 temp FLOAT)""" % (rom)
        cursor.execute(createsqltable)
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO %s (timestamp, temp) VALUES (%s,%s)""",(rom,timestampdata,temperatuur))
        db.commit()
    except:     
        db.rollback()

## CLOSE THE DATABASE
db.close()
```

The tables are created. But the data never makes it.

Before the above code, I had some other code which did work, but I wasn't happy about the tablenames. I've put some ` at line 10:

```
temp FLOAT)""" % (`rom`)
```

This created the table as 'tablename' instead of tablename

And I had the following change at line 12: (see the first `%s`)

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO `%s` (timestamp, temp) VALUES (%s,%s)""",(rom,timestampdata,temperatuur))
```

Which added the data nicely into the 'tablename' table

Now I removed some `  and the table got created OK, but the data never makes it to the table.
I've read a few posts from others, but I can't seem to fix it (I think I've tried all the ` ' " combinations)

And a merry Xmas to you :)

2014-01-04 I've changed the code to:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO {0} (timestamp, temp) VALUES (%s,%s)""".format(a), (b,c))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried different possibilities and came up with the following working solutions:

```
sql = "insert into %s (timestamp, temp) values (%s)" % (a, "%s, %s")  
cursor.execute(sql,(timestampdata,temperatuur))
```

Or

```
def datainsertdef(a,b,c):
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO `{0}` (timestamp, temp) VALUES (%s,%s)""".format(a), (b,c))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO `%s` (timestamp, temp) VALUES (%s,%s)""",(rom,timestampdata,temperatuur))
```

to

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO `%s` (timestamp, temp) VALUES (%s,%s)""" % (rom,timestampdata,temperatuur))
```

This may just be a string formatting error. There is another way to do this in python 3, if you are using it. I would suggest using the python3 method if its available. For more information, look at http://www.diveintopython3.net/strings.html#formatting-strings

Also, in the createsqltable variable, you need to change

```
temp FLOAT)""" % (rom)
```

to

```
 temp FLOAT)""" % (rom,)
```

that could cause errors.

Comment: I've tried your change, but it's not working.
Thank you for pointing me to the difference in python 3. I would like to use it, but for mysql usage, I've read a few times that I should stick with python 2.7, right?

Comment: You can use python3, as long as you use the right library. PyMySQL looks promising, and from their example, it looks exactly the same as the library you are using. https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/example.py

Comment: I've tried python 2.7 and 3.2 with MySQLdb, oursql and PyMySQL. But I can't seem to get data in to dynamic tables.
I like Python programming, but the MySQL database isn't my cup of tea. Perhaps there is some kind of debug option, so I can see what's going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried executing these SQl queries in the default MySQL console? I will try out this code and see if it has any issues.

Comment: The mysql console commands, especially the dynamic insertion, is not equal to the mysqldb module (for what I've tested).  
This works:  

`cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO 28AA507A0500009E (timestamp, temp) VALUES (%s,%s)""",(timestampdata,temperatuur)) `  
But this doesn't:  
`cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO %s (timestamp, temp) VALUES (%s,%s)""",(rom,timestampdata,temperatuur)) `

Comment: after 5 day's of trying and reading I have to find another way to accomplish my goal. perhaps with perl or php.
I can't get it to work even with preparing the execution code in a separate "string", or I'm doing something wrong. It doesn't feel good.

Comment: Maybe one of your rom values are not tables. Try printing out every one of them and make sure that the tables exist in your database. That is the only other possible error I can see here. If there is a bug somewhere else in your code that incorrectly loads j_decoded["one-wire"].items(), then that may be causing your error.

Comment: The following code works partially:  
I'm adding 3 entry's in 3 different tables, and for some reason the 2nd table doesn't get filled. I removed all the tables so the script can create them again, but no go. I do now get it working for 2 out of 3 :)  
  
`sql = "insert into %s (timestamp, temp) values (%s)" % (a, "%s, %s")`  
`cursor.execute(sql,(timestampdata,temperatuur))`

Comment: Again I found a new option to add data to a dynamic table via: `cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO {0} (timestamp, temp) VALUES (%s,%s)""".format(a), (b,c))`  
I've triple checked the tables exist, but for some reason only it gives me also a problem with only the 2nd data entry: `Database.MySQLError :
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '28012E7A050000F5 (timestamp, temp) VALUES ('2014-01-04 14:46:58',23.94)' at line 1")`  
For some reason only the 2nd entry gives a syntax error?